# Why when outside the installation directory do I get passenger: command not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have just built a RackSpace cloud server with Ubuntu 12 LTS and performed a "standard" Ruby on Rails installation.  I created a user (bob) and added it to the sudu group.

I then logged out of root and logged in as bob. Then issued `sudo su` from the `/home/bob` directory. I then installed everything needed to run the Rails Application 'as root'.

I then installed the Rails code in `/home/bob` and passenger started up when I issued:

```
RAILS_ENV=production passenger start -p 3000
```

however, since I want to run multiple Rails applications on this server, I then created another directory `/home/bob/newapp` and installed Rails code there.  (ideally I would want to put all the different Rails applications in their own subdirectory below `/home/bob`)

When I issue the command (shown below) from `/home/bob/newapp`

```
RAILS_ENV=production passenger start -p 3000
```

I get

> passenger: command not found

why is passenger only accessible from `/home/bob` ?

NEWS: just discovered, passenger is 'available' until the moment I complete the edit of the content of `/config/database.yml` thus as long as I do NOT edit the `database.yml` file, passenger will start.  After I edit `database.yml`  the "passenger: command not found" appears. How bizarre is that?

SNAP:  looks like when I installed passenger it used Ruby-2.1.1 however the old application wants ruby-1.9.3-p194.  I need to figure out how to get passenger to run with ruby 1.9.3 or install a second version of passenger  (???)

More News:
Thank you,Hongli, for your response. I followed your links/suggestion to read the passenger documentation. I had read it before without recognizing the needed information. This time I found the "magical" command:

```
rvm-exec ruby-version ruby -S (eg: rvm-exec ruby-1.9.3-p194 ruby -S )
```

this has turned out to be very helpful, although I did end up following a process which has resulted in two different version of passenger being installed.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [About environment variables](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_the_path_environment_variable) section of the Phusion Passenger manual to learn what "command not found" errors are, why they occur, and what you can generally do about them.

In your case, entering /home/bob automatically makes RVM change your PATH to include a specific Ruby version's bin directory. Read the [When the system has multiple Ruby interpreters](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_when_the_system_has_multiple_ruby_interpreters) section of the Phusion Passenger manual to learn how to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

The article Hongli suggested I read definitely moved me in the correct direction.

The use of: rvm-exec 'ruby-version' ruby -S allows me to get passenger started, provided a version of passenger has been installed using the version of ruby required by the Rails application.

Thus if I load up a Rails application built with ruby-1.9.3-p194, I will need a version of passenger installed with the same version of ruby.

If I load up another Rails application built with ruby-1.9.3-p286, I will need a version of passenger installed with that version of ruby.

Then starting each version of passenger can be accomplished with the rvm-exec command with the appropriate ruby version.

Perhaps there is a more elegant solution, but the above works for me.